# Find & replace for specific columns (not the whole range)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, scripting, google-sheets-formula

this is something that keeps bothering me lately. I need to figure out a way to use find & replace for specific columns in a google sheet, but not for the whole range.

I've tried selecting multiple columns with CTRL, but seems like it only works for one column or each column in a range.

Are there any workarounds you know¿ I'm going to apply this to a sheet with 50k+ rows by the way

Here is more context:

[image: EXAMPLE SHEETS AND FIND & REPLACE FUNCTION]

I want to use the find & replace function as in the image, however instead of searching in all columns(all levels) I just want to search within level 1 columns, so A, D, G

Comment: Hi there @SafakAtakanCelik! I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please explain what criteria you use to search for the columns? What do you mean by `but not for the whole range`? What do you want to replace the column with?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough. I'm just going to search for simple string values in the cells that are under those columns, and change those to another string. So it's basically a simple find & replace function, but the find function needs to be run on multiple columns. I'm adding more context to the post itself.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron, I just updated the post, it should be a lot clear now. Do you have any idea on how to do this? It would save me hours of work :D

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, entering multiple specific ranges is not supported within find and replace. you will need to do this 1 range per time.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with google app scripts or something else? Or is it simply not possible at all?

Comment: @SafakAtakanCelik not sure about the app script, but my guess is that it could be doable with a script. I shall redirect your Q under the scripting tag

Comment: Can you do that? I changed the tags, I hope this works :D

Comment: @SafakAtakanCelik if you mean editing your question - yes I can. if you mean writing a script - sadly no, apologies.

Comment: I meant editing my question of course, I wouldn't ask you to write the script :D That should by me job, but any help from someone is appreciated.